# ''it seems it was only yesterday'' vs ''it seems like only yesterday''

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, synonyms, syntax

What's the difference entre : ex.1 : It’s been over a year since we met, but it seems it was only yesterday.

ex.2: It’s been over a year since we met, but it seems like only yesterday.

Does the verb "like" here have the same meaning as the auxiliary "was"? And would these sentences have the same meaning if ''only'' were removed?

Comment: There is no verb like there.

Answer (score 1):

If A **seems to be** B then A is very probably B, usually because of evidence. If A **seems like** B, then A resembles B in some way, but may not be identical.

Sentence (1) does not make sense, because we use a definite phrase after 'it seems' (e.g. 'it **was**') to mean that something, often contrary to what we had thought, has turned out to actually be the case - I thought that Joe was a nice guy, but it seems that he is a murderer. I thought his car was a Honda but it seems it is a Toyota. We can't say 'It has been over a year since we met, but I now know that it was yesterday'. That is contradictory.

Sentence (2) does make sense, because we use a comparative phrase after 'it seems' (e.g. '**like** it was') to mean that something feels like it is the case, when actually it is not. Often exaggeration is used - my shopping weighs 10 kilos, but it **seems like** it weighs 50 (because I was tired). We talked for an hour but it **seemed like** five minutes (because I enjoyed it so much, or it was so interesting).